# Grammarly doesn't work on an asp.net textbox

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome-extension

I have installed Grammarly Chrome Extension on the Chrome browser. This extension works fine on sites such as Facebook and StackOverflow body area when viewed in Chrome. However, my personal website created in asp.net web forms has several asp.net textboxes and Grammarly doesn't work there. A red line shows under a spelling error but when hovered over with the mouse, Grammarly doesn't make any suggestions. I have added data-text="true" in the aspx page which has the textbox. Still doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like something to be asked on Grammarly support forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Grammarly support team, the textbox should have a height greater than 38px and the width greater than 301px. Once I resized my textbox with these dimensions, Grammarly started working!

Comment: That seems arbitrary.